# How do I prevent a function from finishing

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

My plan is to create a function that keep looping.

The function shall never finish

```
Public Shared Async Function checkNewlines(txt As TextBox) As Task
    Do
        Await checkNewLinesAloop(txt)
    Loop While True

    LogEvents("This shouldn't be called")
    Dim b = 1
    b = b + 1
End Function
```

Something like this.

Surely

```
LogEvents("This shouldn't be called")
Dim b = 1
b = b + 1
```

should never be called right?

The function is called at

```
Private Async Sub CmdSoundAlarm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSoundAlarm.Click
    Await startAndStopClickingButton2(sender, Async Function() As Task
                                                  Await CoinClass.checkNewlines(TextBox1) ' this one never end
                                                  Dim b = 1
                                              End Function)
End Sub
```

and startAndStopClickingButton2 is effectively

```
Public Async Function startAndStopClickingButton2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal SomeSub As System.Func(Of Task)) As Task
    startClickingButton(sender)
    Await SomeSub.Invoke()
    Dim c = 1 ' This one should never be called
    stopClickingButton(sender)
End Function
```

Well for some reason stopClickingButton(sender) is executed. It shouldn't be.

The way checkNewLines(txt as TextBox) is written do loop should never exit

Comment: Does `CheckNewLines` actually return, or does `StartAndStopClickingButton` somehow return before `CheckNewLines` does?

Comment: What happens when you don't pass a delegate to `StartAndStopClickingButton` and instead pass `TextBox1` and you call `Await Coinclass.Checknewlines(TextBox1)` in `StartAndStopPressingButton`?

Comment: For some reason I cannot put breakpoint after the loop in checkNewLines

However, end function is reached.

I haven't tried your suggestion.